# Logs de comandos ejecutados via terminal

Tags: linux, shell, consola, centos, terminal

Existe algún archivo `.log` donde se puedan consultar los comandos aplicados vía terminal en `Linux`, Por lo regular aplico el comando `history` para verificar comandos anteriormente ejecutados sin embargo en esta ocasion borraron el historial y no tengo rastro de que usuario que aplico comando.

Comment: No estoy seguro de que esta pregunta sea **sobre programación**. `Bash` guarda los últimos comandos en el archivo `$HOME/.bash_history`. Los guarda **al salir de bash**, así que solo puedes ver los tecleados **en la sesión anterior**.

Comment: `rm -r` es un comando para borrar de forma recursiva, no para consultar el historial de comando.

Comment: es correcto lo que me comentas, lo que estoy buscando es un archivo donde consultar un comando ejecutado, rm -r es un comando de ejemplo del que quisiera localizar o un comando mkdir

Comment: Tal y como está redactada la pregunta, casi parece que lo que se busca es que un incauto ejecute `rm -r`  desde el terminal. Sería bueno editar la pregunta y poner un comando diferente (ya que el comando usado es indiferente para la pregunta en sí)

Comment: Te recomiendo que periódicamente ejecutes history > nombre_archivo esto para guardar el histórico en algún archivo en una ruta especifica y no te vuelva a suceder lo mismo de que lo borraron, de hecho puedes automatizarlo por medio del demonio cronos para que se ejecute cada determinado tiempo.

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza la variable HISTFILE, en ella le dices donde escribe el history. 
Así sabrás quien ha hecho qué y en qué sesión.

export HISTFILE = "(`/bin/date '+%H.%M.%S_%d-%m-%Y`')."`whoami`".log"
readonly HISTFILE